# having trouble with yahoo weather feeds

Tags: oauth, rss, yahoo, weather

I am having problems using regional weather rss feeds that i have been using for many years, and am not much of a programmer, so i do not understand what i could do to get my feeds up and running again... Could someone please help me?
here is one of the weather feeds that worked for me until 2 days ago:

http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=3563&u=c

is there something i can add to it to make it work again?

Thanks for any hints

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately i had the same problem.
It seems that yahoo changed the URL to

```
http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/forecastrss?w=”+postal+”&u=c
```

instead of http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=3563&u=c

Comment: Thanks to your information, i was able to restart all of my feeds... But now since 3 days, it stopped working again!.. I have read about the thing yahoo has introduced in their feed that require "an authorization code" to be able to retrieve the weather feed, but i do not understand how to set it up in order to obtain the correct URL for the weather feed i need... And it seems i cannot find any information on a way to continue using Yahoo weather feeds... Any help is welcome!